# background not setting up

Tags: html, css, background

Hello I am trying to set an image as a background using a css file in an index.html, however I use the css declaration the image will not be displayed even if you put it on html, can you please help me figure it out, thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Solution</title>
    <style>
       body{
        background: url("img/notarde.png")
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    HI
  </body>
</html>

CssFile
body{
  background: url("img/notarde.png")
}
```

Comment: Not a lot we can do but guess without the **actual** image

Comment: Have you added the reference to your CSS file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

Comment: @SimonM. : Question states that image is not visible when used from CSS file, it's only visible when using within HTML file

Comment: when i did not have the <style> I had the <<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/notarde.png" >>

Comment: Did you forget to add `;` at the end of your line of code? It could be as simple as that.. So you'd have `body { background : url("...") ; }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your style in `<style></style>` it is not needed to add the same content in a CSS file to do it.

However, if you wants to use an external CSS file you can add this line between the `<head></head>` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="THE_PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE">
```

Your code works, it must be the path of the image that went wrong.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/cgyyexms/1/)

Comment: when i did not have the <style> I han the <<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/notarde.png" >>

Comment: Must be a CSS file in the `href` like `styles.css` for example, not an image

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the stylesheet in the index.html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[your css file path]">
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: yes I did it ... I had it included to the html file

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced the CSS file in your HTML Page?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Specify the CSS file name and path in **href** like `href="CSS/filename.css"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Solution</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  HI
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when i did not have the <style> I han the <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/notarde.png" >>